# canvas rendering

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

If you try to render an image outside of the canvas width and height, will the computer still try to render it and use resources to try to render it? I'm just trying to find out if it's better to do a check for if the image is inside the canvas before trying to render it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it still does the rendering on an infinitely large invisible plane, so it would be wise to programmatically detect whether an object is "visible" or not, just as you would want to do in any other programming language.  No sense in going through the logic, if you don't need to.

See this from the [spec for canvas](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-model):

> When a shape or image is painted, user agents must follow these steps,
>   in the order given (or act as if they do):
>
> Render the shape or image onto an infinite transparent black bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I think when you want to optimize performance you need to build tester which check the frame per secend according the Load.
and check with the change and no change in this way you can be sure what is right to do.
look here in the top left side of the page web 
[Demo tester by frame per secend](http://codeincomplete.com/projects/racer/v4.final.html)